# div display issue with jq

Tags: jquery

Modified a fiddle to do multiples but it has an error with mutiples... when link 1 is clicked, div 1 and 2 are affected.

when link 2 is clicked, only div 2 is affected.

what could be the issue here?

http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/zsMaE/3/

```
  function deselect() {
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
            $("#contact").removeClass("selected");
        });    
    }

    $(function() {
        $("#contact").live('click', function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                deselect();               
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 

                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        $(".close").live('click', function() {
            deselect();
            return false;
        });
    });

    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);
    };



    function deselect() {
        $(".pop2").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
            $("#contact2").removeClass("selected");
        });    
    }

    $(function() {
        $("#contact2").live('click', function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                deselect();               
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $(".pop2").slideFadeToggle(function() { 

                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        $(".close").live('click', function() {
            deselect();
            return false;
        });
    });

    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the "deselect()" function twice. You could rename the second one to "deselect2", but there's a better way to do this.

Instead of giving the links unique ids, give them the same class (say "contact"). Then you can easily assign the same click event handler to them. Then rewrite the "deselect()" function to take the link as a parameter. To associate the "messagepop" divs with the links, you could given them unique ids, and then set the hrefs of the links to be the ids of the divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="messagepop" id="pop1">ANYTHING HERE 1</div>
<div class="messagepop" id="pop2">ANYTHING HERE 2</div>
<a href="#pop1" class="contact">Contact Us 1</a>
<a href="#pop2" class="contact">Contact Us 2</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function select($link) {
    $link.addClass('selected');
    $($link.attr('href')).slideFadeToggle(function () {});
}

function deselect($link) {
    $($link.attr('href')).slideFadeToggle(function () {
        $link.removeClass('selected');
    });
}

$('.contact').click(function () {
    var $link = $(this);
    if ($link.hasClass('selected')) {
        deselect($link);
    } else {
        select($link);
    }
    return false;
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/zsMaE/6/)

**UPDATE FOR QUESTION IN COMMENT**

If you want only one of the `<div>`s visible at a time, you could keep track of which one is visible and hide it before you make another visible, but it is easier to just hide them all before showing one. The `<div>`s all have the "messagepop" class, so it is easy to select them all.

```
function select($link) {
    $link.addClass('selected');
    $('.messagepop:visible').slideFadeToggle(function () {});
    $($link.attr('href')).slideFadeToggle(function () {});
}
```

Note: If we were hiding them with `.hide()`, I would probably use `'.messagepop'` for the selector and hide all of them, but since `.slideFadeToggle()` toggles them, I went with `'.messagepop:visible'` to limit the toggling to just the visible ones.

Comment: thats an awesome way to do it! thankyou @John but what would i add to this to make only one able to pop up at a time? many thanks

Comment: @Hush Pro - I updated my answer. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: thankyou very much @John much appreciated, cleared this up a treat.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring 2 times deselect ! so obviously the second override the first

do a plugin

```
$.fn.extend({deselect : function () {$(this).removeClass('deselect')} });
```

then bind at once your 2 contact (put a class to them) then use `$(this)`